# Extracting a Gzip-file leads to a Gzip-file

Tags: gzip, rdf, semantic-web, linked-data

I have a nquads file 'articles.nq.gz', (can be found at http://opencitations.net/source-data/ )After using the command

```
gunzip articles.nq.gz
```

I end up with `'acrticles.nq'`, but the document isn't recognized as an .`nquads` type, but is still considered as an `Gzip-file.`
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I doubt that `gunzip articles.nq.gz` produces `acrticles.nq`, and expect it actually produces `articles.nq`.  What does `head articles.nq` show?

Comment: "the document isn't recognized as an .nquads type, but is still considered as an Gzip-file."  Isn't recognized _by what_?  What's trying to read the file and reporting that it's a gzipped file?

Comment: No file was found at: http://opencitations.net/data/complete/articles.nq.gz